# Convert ffmpeg audio volumedetect negative dB levels to common loudness positive dB levls

Tags: ffmpeg, audio, loudness

I have a process sampling `mean_volume` levels from `$ ffmpeg -af 'volumedetect' ...` [which outputs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#volumedetect) negative `-##.## dB` measurements where 0 dB is very loud and -100 dB is very quiet.  I need to line those measurements up with "common" loudness scales lining up different positive dB levels with noise environments we encounter such as:

- 30 dB = Leaves rustling, soft music, whisper
- 40 dB = Average home noise
- 60 dB = Normal conversation, background music
- 70 dB = Office noise, inside car at 60 mph
- 75 dB = Vacuum cleaner, average radio

How should one go about converting the negative dB measurements from `ffmpeg` to positive dB values on such scales?

(There are many sources for the "common" loudness scales I refer to here, including built into various smartphone apps for measuring environmental noise and on various web pages such as where I copied [the sample above from](https://myhealth.alberta.ca/Health/Pages/conditions.aspx?hwid=tf4173#targetText=Normal%20conversation%20is%20about%2060,such%20as%20earplugs%20or%20earmuffs.), and they all roughly agree.  I would assume this conversion would require me to do some sort of "calibration" to get measurements from both the `ffmpeg` output and something on these common scales.  That's something I can do using said apps. Perfect accuracy isn't the goal and isn't required here, just a reasonable rough mapping from the `ffmpeg` output onto to these common scales.)

Comment: Try the replaygain filter. See https://sound.stackexchange.com/a/44522

Comment: @Gyan *How* would I use the replaygain filter to do the conversion I'm trying to do?

At any rate, that certainly seems like that's the stackexchange where this question belongs.  I didn't find that one when I was trying to find the best one, I assume because it's beta.  But thanks for the pointer!  Can someone move this question to https://sound.stackexchange.com?

Comment: The filter output prints out the gain required to achieve 89 dB. So `89 - gain_value` is the measured loudness.

Comment: Thanks, @Gyan!  That seems to be working well.

Comment: Oh, if you want to write that up as an answer, I'll call this answered, @Gyan.